# Flutter Button (GestureDetector) with Navigator.push function cannot be pressed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to navigate the page to the Sign-up Screen with a SizedBox and a GestureDetector as a parent.
This is the code starting with the Transform.translate Widget:

```
              offset: Offset(117.0, 455.17),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
                  );
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 150.0,
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign Up',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 26,
                          color: const Color(0xff202020),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          height: 0.9615384615384616,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                ),
              )
          ),
```

I'm pretty new to Flutter, so if some more code or information at all is needed, just tell me :)

Comment: Do you want the `onTap` of the `GestureDetector ` to be detected and not the `onPressed` of the `FlatButton` ?

Comment: Oops, a little mistake. I tried to remove one and leave the other one but both times it didn't work

Comment: Your sample doesn't include anything that would be causing this (that I can see). This could be explained by having another GestureDetector further up the widget tree. Can you include more? Also, try seeing if onTap is ever called (something simple like a breakpoint or a print statement)

Comment: @David there isn't any other GestureDetector. And btw it already worked once but it suddenly stopped working. Here is the Code of the entire main.dart file:

https://pastebin.com/cp8PqxXV

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541250/transform-gesture-detector-in-flutterwith-stack) is a similar issue like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because of your transform widget. However, looking at your code, it seems to me it's not the widget you want anyway (correct me if I'm wrong).

What you seem to be trying to do is position your child widgets in the `Stack`. You shouldn't use a translate widget for this, you should instead use the `Align` and `Positioned` widgets. The position the widget within the parent widget, and since your parent widget is a stack, this will let you place widgets on top of each other.

The `Transform.translate` widget is for other situations such as animating components or moving visual elements (I've used it for implementing an `InteractiveViewer` before it existed, for example), however, it shouldn't be the default choice and has extra complications.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it as soon as possible and (hopefully) confirm your answer!